# jos-Error: Unable to load renderer class

Tags: ajax, joomla

I'm creating a component with AJAX, after clicking on submit button I get `jos-Error: Unable to load renderer class` error. My guess is that controller cant find view:

```
public function savex()
{
    JRequest::setVar('view', 'komentarai');

    parent::display();
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is right.

Also some other errors I get (more specific about controller)

```
JController -> execute() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_siena\siena.php:20
SienaController -> savex() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:761
JController -> display() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_siena\controller.php:26
```

A full list of error message:

```
jos-Error: Unable to load renderer class

JSite -> dispatch() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:42
JComponentHelper :: renderComponent() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\application.php:197
JComponentHelper :: executeComponent() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\helper.php:351
require_once() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\helper.php:383
JController -> execute() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_siena\siena.php:20
SienaController -> savex() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:761
JController -> display() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_siena\controller.php:26
JController -> getView() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:677
JError :: raiseError() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:903
JError :: raise() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:251
JError :: throwError() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:176
call_user_func_array() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:214
JError :: handleCallback()
call_user_func() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:765
plgSystemRedirect :: handleError()
JError :: customErrorPage() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\plugins\system\redirect\redirect.php:109
JDocumentError -> render() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:798
JDocumentError -> _loadTemplate() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\document\error\error.php:107
require_once() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\document\error\error.php:135
Gantry -> displayModules() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\templates\gantry\error.php:40
GantryModulesRenderer :: display() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\gantry\core\gantry.class.php:867
GantryFeatureDropdownMenu -> render() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\gantry\core\renderers\gantrymodulesrenderer.class.php:65
JDocument -> loadRenderer() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\templates\gantry\features\dropdownmenu.php:50
JError :: raiseError() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\document\document.php:926
JError :: raise() @ C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:251
```

Comment: I found out what was wrong... In views folder file view.html.php have to be renamed to view.raw.php ...

Comment: Create an answer and accept it when possible to let people know it has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong... In views folder file view.html.php have to be renamed to view.raw.php